# Remove check marks for materials check box dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to add a function to a click event that will uncheck everything.

```html
<mat-autocomplete [panelWidth]='290' panelClass="myPanelClass">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.name">
        <div>
            <mat-checkbox
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="toggleSelection(item)">
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Check it and let me know your feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you.To Achieve that you can check my code below=>

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select  #select multiple>
    <div class="select-all">
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="allSelected"
                        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                        (change)="toggleAllSelection()">Select All</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <mat-option (click)="optionClick()" *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('select') select: MatSelect;
  allSelected=false;
   foods: any[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
  toggleAllSelection() {
    if (this.allSelected) {
      this.select.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => item.select());
    } else {
      this.select.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => item.deselect());
    }
  }
   optionClick() {
    let newStatus = true;
    this.select.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => {
      if (!item.selected) {
        newStatus = false;
      }
    });
    this.allSelected = newStatus;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Please check the demo code on that link => [Stackblitz Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-all-checkbox-6g4x8z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).